# OctoberCMS include JavaScript vendor packages in plugin

Tags: npm, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I've created my own plugin in OctoberCMS. Some of my plugin's features make use of JavaScript, which can be put in `author/plugin/assets/js` folder and added to a plugin component by using the `addJs` function as described in the [docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#component-assets). You can even combine your plugin's JS files like [this](https://octobercms.com/forum/post/combining-a-set-of-javascript-files-within-a-component).

That's all good, but my plugin is making use of some external JS libraries. I know I can install them with npm in my site theme, but then my plugin wouldn't work for anyone using a theme that didn't install those libraries.

So what I'm asking is: How can I include npm dependencies in my plugin?

Comment: hmm why dont you just ship them with your plugin or any issue ? mostly publisher provides stand alone version you can download and use as single file and not as NPM package you can use it

Comment: Because you loose all the advantages NPM provides. Such as easily updating, making sure you don't have duplicate packages, etc. Manually including the vendor file feels a bit like going back to the old days.

Comment: hmm then make a bundle of your files and use that `bundle.js` as your js file and ship with that. so you can have best of both world :)